# Help with char input and printing in C++

Tags: c++, input, character

i want to read characters from the console and print them one after another only if they have a certain value.

Well i tried using something like this:

```
char c;

while (c != '\n') {
       c = getch();
       if (printable(c)) cout << c; // where printable is a function which checks 
                                    // if the character is of a certain value
}
```

But this doesn't work as it prints all the characters, so any ideas what should i use?

Thanks a lot!

**Edit**

Well i want to make polynomial calculator in which the user inputs the terms until pressed Enter, but if for example the user inputs 'r' or 'R' it will reset the input or 'q' and 'Q' to quit the program and also even if the user inputs illegall characters like '@',',',';', etc (also i don't want 'r' or 'q' printed) it won't print them on screen.

Also here's the printable function:

```
bool printable(char c) 
    {

        return (
                  ((int(c) > 42 && int(c) < 123) || isspace(c)) && int(c) != 44 && int(c) != 46 && int(c) != 47 && 
                  int(c) != 58 && int(c) != 59 && 
                  int(c) != 60 && int(c) != 61 && int(c) != 62 && int(c) != 63 && int(c) != 64 && int(c) != 65 && 
                  int(c) != 91 && int(c) != 92 && int(c) != 93 && int(c) != 95 && int(c) != 96
                ); 
    }
```

Comment: show us what your printable function looks like.

Comment: @Vlad - how are you going to represent powers of a polynomial?  Or are you only looking for some coefficients ?

Comment: @JonH - I'm using another char variable called lc(last char) and when lc = '^' i know c is value of polynomials power and i know i have to stop reading the power when c is not a digit (for that i use isdigit(c) )

Comment: @Vlad - suddenly you are adding a lot more defintion, that is why you haven't got much good help so far. you did not include ALL the details and that is what we need. Im not trying to be mean but we cannot read your mind. You just commented that you have another function that checks the last character, how did you assume we knew this ? Re-edit your entire post showing clearly what you want and provide ALL the source code with comments and details.

Comment: well i wanted a solution to the printing problem because with the code i currently posted after presing Enter it prints the inputed characthers again.

Comment: Because you have \n.  It is supposed to be \r.

Comment: yes that was it, now i need to check if the characters are correctly added as termms to the polynomial

Thanks JonH & all others!

Comment: @Vlad No problem you will need to probably re-edit your entire post, provide all details with all the functions you have and then you might be able to get some help.  Also is this homework ?

Comment: no i simply want to learn new things!

Comment: Also if i'll need help with the polynomial calculator i'll probably better post a new question

Comment: @Vlad if that is the case and this issue is solved then give credit to the person you feel helped you by marking the question as answered.  Then start a new thread.

Comment: @Vlad - (continued from above) - I think that being all of this dialouge over a simple \n or \r that it is right to simply accept an answer so that this thread is basically not left open.  And re-create a new thread as you have mentioned.  I wanted to mention that in the new thread you should include all relevant information so that we can help you including all code and functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to change your cout statement to `cout << "You just typed: " << c;`
That way you can actually see if you've hit the if condition successfully.  Also post printable().

Here is a sample of just grabbing a char, not sure why you are using getch() you should use cin.get, but anyhow for your example:

```
bool isPrintable(char c)
 {
     bool isItPrintable=false;

     if ((int)c >= 65)
        isItPrintable=true;

        return isItPrintable;
 }

int main()
{
    char c;

    while (c != '\r')
      {
           c=getch();
           if (isPrintable(c))
             {
                cout << "You just entered: " << c << endl;
             }
      }
    return 0;
}
```

For anyone wondering, getch() is available in `conio.h`.  In my case I am just checking the int representation of the character and if it is > 65 returning true else false.

**EDIT**

Vlad the reason why w and z both show up is their decimal representation of w is 119 and z is 123.  Now your isPrintable function has an if condition which allows for this:

```
(int(c) > 42 && int(c) < 123)
```

This will evaluate to TRUE  so if you do not want a w you need to restrict that range.

Comment: I don't want the input to be printed twice. For example if i input two polynomials, i want the screen to show only:


P1 = term1 +/- term2...  //read until Enter pressed 

P2 = term1 +/- term2...  //read until Enter pressed

Comment: I'm using getch() because afaik this function doesn't print characters as they are read.

Am I wrong?

Comment: @Vlad - then you shouldn't use getch().

Comment: @Vlad - you can use it you just need to clearly define the problem.  Do you want it so that it only takes x's?  I noticed you said in your example 2x^2wez +x +1 it should only come back as 2x^2+x+1.  You have to validate this string when it is typed in.  Clearly define the inputs and outputs and someone can help you.

Comment: @Vlad use '\r' instead of '\n' you are looking for a carriage return.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to do something like this?

```
bool printable(char c)
{
    if ((c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z'))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int main()
{
  char c = ' ';

    while (c != '\r') {
           c = _getch();
    if (printable(c)) cout << c; // where printable is a function which checks 
                                        // if the character is of a certain value
    }  
}
```

This would print out only letters and ends the program on pressing return key

Comment: not only letters, but numbers also.

If i type 2x^2wez + x + 1, it should show on screen only 2x^2 + x + 1;

Comment: @Vlad that is your problem, your printable function allows for w as its ascii representation in decimal is 119

Comment: Well i'm thinking on putting a condition so that if the variable name was read it won't print any other letter than the one which coresponds to the variable name(x in my example);

Answer (score 1):

There are many methods to check if a character is printable:

1. `isprint()` (library routine)
2. Compare character by character (via
   `if`)
3. Search a string of known characters
4. Table lookup

### Library routine `isprint`

This function comes with both the C and C++ language.  Read a reference page: [isprint function](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/c/string/isprint)

### Comparing character by character

In your function you try something like:
    `return c == 65;`
But a more readable syntax is:
    `return c == 'a';`

### Search a string of known characters

Create a const string of *printable* characters and search it:

```
bool is_print(char c)
{
    static const std::string    printable_chars("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");
    return printable_chars.find(c) != std::string::npos;
}
```

### Table lookup:

```
bool is_print(char c)
{
    static const char printable_chars[] = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'};
    return std::binary_search(printable_chars,
                              printable_chars + sizeof(printable_chars),
                              c);
}
```

Comment: nice suggestion, but i won't need those as the solution was to simply change Enter condition from '\n' to '\r'.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't printing all the characters, your terminal window is echoing the characters you type. You would see this more clearly if you ran it as `program < some_file`

The code has other flaws (*e.g.* what does it do when there are no more characters?) but those are other questions.